# SQL Not displaying items which are < than yesterdays date & before 3pm today

Tags: sql

Its a lending an item table, I can show item which are forward from today's date.  I need to display records including today's date and only upto 3pm today

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Lending
WHERE convert(DATE,'20/08/2022', 103) >= GETDATE();
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Both convert and GETDATE are product specific functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Lending
WHERE convert(DATE,'22/08/2022', 103) >= GETDATE()-1 AND GETDATE() < '2022-08-22 15:00'
```

that worked for me, just added a little to my original attempt, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Lending
WHERE date_col
      BETWEEN
          DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE())) AND  -- today at midnight
          DATEADD(mi, 900, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()))   -- today at 3pm
```

Note that 3pm is 900 minutes past midnight, hence the above calculation.

Comment: Great solutions, although, my Dates field is just a date, or a number of dates in the format of 01/08/2022 02/08/2022 03/08/2022, each date has a space and I'm just running a LIKE function, my solutions works, but doesnt display todays date before 3PM.

Comment: If your field is really just a date sans time component, then does it even make sense to speak of 3pm?

Comment: I dont think I explained it very well, its referring to a calendar date and will only allow to borrowing of an item firstly running a search on todays date, but i also want it to run the query on whether its before 3PM

Answer (score 0):

You can try using datetime instead of date:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Lending 
    WHERE column_name between 
    cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) 
    and dateadd(hour,15,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, my field Dates is NCHAR which contains one or many dates formated (eg) 01/08/2022 02/08/2022 03/08/2022, that code results in an out-of-range value

Comment: My reply answers your initial question, given the information you provided. What you probably need is some job-procedure that will execute at exact time in your online db, given the time zones etc match, its completely different to your original question